# Toric Fan for the Du Val's singularities D_n and E_n

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, toric-varieties, resolution-of-singularities

Let us consider the Du Val's singularities. 
i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_Val_singularity.

It is well known that they are classified by ADE, because the exceptional divisors arising in the resulution of the singularities intersect in a way which can be represented by a Dynkin diagram of type A, D or E.

The question is the following. For singularities of type $A_n$ I know one explicit description in terms of toric geometry. The toric fan for the singular space has 1-dimensional cones given by $v_1=(0,1), \ v_2=(1,n+1)$ and a 2-dimensional cone which has faces $v_1$ and $v_2$. The resolution can be described by adding $n$ further 1-dimensional cones subdividing the 2-dimensional one. One can then very explicitly see the exceptional divisors, compute intersection numbers, etc.

Now let us consider the singularities of type $D_n$ or $E_i, i=6,7,8$. Is it possible to describe them in toric goemetry? Is it known what is the toric fan for those spaces? I did some literature search, but I couldn't find anything. On the other hand, I strongly believe the answer to this question must be known.

I apologize if I expressed my question using a sloppy or non-proper language. I am a physicist.

Comment: $D_n$ and $E_n$ are non-toric.

Comment: Thanks. Byt why? Is there a way to see this, or could you point me to a reference?

Comment: One way to see this is by checking that any toric Gorenstein singularity is of type $A_n$.

Comment: May I ask for a reference discussing this statement? I am just starting to learn these things, sorry.